# Error when trying to estimateGas()

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, gas-estimate

I'm getting the following error:

```
{ code: 13, message: 'execution simulation failed: status = 106' }
```

When executing this code:

```
const gasEstimate = await WJEWELContract.methods.mint(amount).estimateGas({from: account.address}, function(estimatedGas) { console.log(estimatedGas) });
```

WJEWELContract is just an ERC20 with a "mint" method.

Does anybody know what this can be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't calling the method the right way:

```
    const gasEstimate = WJEWELContract.methods.mint(amount)
        .estimateGas(
            {
                from: account.address,
                gasPrice: _gasPrice
            }, function(error, estimatedGas) {
                console.log(estimatedGas)
            }
        )
    });
```